# Can you use a theme with side bar items with shoreditch?

Tags: drupal, theme, shoreditch

I'm experimenting with the latest version of Shoreditch on Drupal and it looks great with a theme like Seven (that has no sidebars).

It seems to work with Bootstrap - which does have side bars. But, the sidebars in bootstrap seem to push everything to far to the right.

Is this a bug? Or is shoreditch designed to take up the whole width of the screen and I should try to use it and have sidebars?

Comment: Did you come up with a good solution? I also would like to use something that is full width at backend like Seven - but still want sidebars

Comment: Nope, no solution. It seems like it will work best without sidebars and we've started exploring ways to replace the sidebars with other methods of display (see for example: https://civicrm.org/extensions/recent-items-menu)

Answer (score 1):

I just tested [Adminimal](https://www.drupal.org/project/adminimal_theme) on a site with shoreditch, and while not pretty, i did get a sidebar

Answer (score 1):

I wrote an extension that is not a clean fix by any means, [shoreditchwpworkarounds](https://lab.civicrm.org/extensions/shoreditchwpworkarounds/), but it might help. I had written it for WordPress, but it should work for Drupal8 also.

Personally I think that removing sidebars is the better option. They use a lot of screen space, and the [Recent Menu Items](https://civicrm.org/extensions/recent-items-menu) or [kamlanguage](https://lab.civicrm.org/extensions/kamlanguage/) extensions can help expose features that were previously blocks.

Comment: fair points. using sidebar has been a go to for us to put in drupal blocks pertaining to the contact on screen. we can find better ways of doing this but has been nice and easy in the past